# Select min and max for each row with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query to select the min and max for each row, with multiple columns.

Here is some data that I'm trying to select from -

```
ITEM NO IDN IDB     IDC     IDE    IDF  IDG     IDH
A33     1.5  1.25    5      14.5   1.89 1.254   1.21
A34     1.6  1.257   5.95   52.1   1.2  1.256   1.235
```

The end result I need is -

```
ITEM NO     MIN   MAX
A33         1.2   14.5
A34         1.2   52.1
```

Is there any simple way of doing this in a sql query?

Comment: i'm slightly confused as to how you're getting the min/max values in your example?

Comment: The `A33` entry has a typo. Min should be 1.21.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have no `NULL` values (as in the sample data), use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select item_no, least(idn, idb, idc, ide, idf, idg, idh) as `min`, 
       greatest(idn, idb, idc, ide, idf, idg, idh) as `max`
from table t;
```

EDIT:

With `NULL` values, this becomes much harder.  One way is if you can define a valid range, then something like this works:

```
select item_no,
       least(coalesce(idn, 999999999), coalesce(idb, 999999999), coalesce(idc, 999999999), coalesce(ide, 999999999), 
             coalesce(idf, 999999999), coalesce(idg, 999999999), coalesce(idh, 999999999)
            ) as `min`, 
       greatest(coalesce(idn, -1), coalesce(idb, -1), coalesce(idc, -1), coalesce(ide, -1), 
                coalesce(idf, -1), coalesce(idg, -1), coalesce(idh, -1)
               ) as `max`
from table t;
```

You can convert back to `NULL` with `case` logic or `nullif()`, if all the values in a row can be `NULL`:

```
select item_no,
       nullif(least(coalesce(idn, 999999999), coalesce(idb, 999999999), coalesce(idc, 999999999), coalesce(ide, 999999999), 
                    coalesce(idf, 999999999), coalesce(idg, 999999999), coalesce(idh, 999999999)
                   ),
              999999999) as `min`, 
       nullif(greatest(coalesce(idn, -1), coalesce(idb, -1), coalesce(idc, -1), coalesce(ide, -1), 
                       coalesce(idf, -1), coalesce(idg, -1), coalesce(idh, -1)
                      ),
              -1) as `max`
from table t;
```

Comment: just a quick sp check on 'greatest' ;)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  Hi, Yeah the table does actually have NULL values, is there any way to filter them out before selecting the least and greatest?

Comment: This solves the problem as described (+1) although the glaring WTF is that the data is not mormalized to begin with.

Comment: If `item_no` really is a unique key into the remaining tuple of columns, this is totally fine. It may be denormalized like this as a result of repeated queries that were not fast enough with many joins, etc. It's very common to see data taken from normalized sources and turned into intermediate tables like this to speed up certain queries.